# adding a hyperlink to kml 'name' tag

Tags: html, google-maps, hyperlink, kml

This is a noob question, but I'm trying to make the 'name' in a kml placemark a hyperlink, but the use of the <![CDATA[ ]]> construct doesn't work for the 'name' tag like it does the 'description' tag. Is there a good way to do this? I'm using this kml in a google maps application.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <Placemark>
<!--      **want hyperlink below!** -->
      <name><![CDATA[<a href='http://www.volcano.si.edu/volcano.cfm?vn=351020'>Ruiz_250_m</a>]]></name>
        <Polygon>
          <outerBoundaryIs>
            <LinearRing>
              <coordinates>
                -76.560000,4.0233333,0
                -76.560000,5.8000000,0
                -74.072222,5.8000000,0
                -74.072222,4.0233333,0
                -76.560000,4.0233333,0
              </coordinates>
            </LinearRing>
          </outerBoundaryIs>
        </Polygon>
     </Placemark>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

Comment: Adding Untyped Name/Value Pairs -> https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/extendeddata (Google will automatically add the link, just write the url without the link markup